# Why would gam() and glm() give different results when no spline terms are included?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model

I have a strange issue where the results of `gam()` and `glm()` differ even though no spline terms are included in the former function. This seems to only happen in cases where the formula is complex and includes a lot of terms (e.g. 10), otherwise the results are equivalent. Specifically, I am using a link function in both cases (`family=Gamma(link="log")`), e.g.:

```
mod.gam <- gam(resp ~ poly(x1,2) + poly(x2,2) + poly(x3,2) + poly(x4,2), data = dat, family=Gamma(link="log"))

mod.glm <- glm(resp ~ poly(x1,2) + poly(x2,2) + poly(x3,2) + poly(x4,2), data = dat, family=Gamma(link="log"))
```

My reason for wanting to use the GAM is that I would also like the flexibility of including a spline term for larger models; e.g.:

```
mod.gam2 <- gam(resp ~ poly(x1,2) + poly(x2,2) + poly(x3,2) + poly(x4,2) + s(x5, x6), data = dat, family=Gamma(link="log"))
```

Perhaps part of the issue is with the `optimizer` or `method` settings in `gam`, but I am unfamiliar with these alternatives. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is that an `mgcv::gam` or a `gam::gam`? I'm pretty sure they use both different optimizers than `glm`.

Comment: And I'm not sure why you would use four second order polynomials instead of penalized smoothers.

Comment: Yes, it's mgcv::gam. The polynomial is just an example. Substitute any complicated linear model formula.